# How to disable BufferRecycler?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jackson

I need to disable BufferRecycler to inspect its effect on garbage collection times.

Any idea how can I achieve that ?

Edit: I overrided _getBufferRecycler method of JsonFactory by returning null and used this JsonFactory instance to construct my ObjectMapper but It did not work. It seems Writer implementations could work with null BufferRecycler but IOContext not.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually something new that may be relevant here: Jackson 2.6 does have a new `JsonFactory.Feature`, `USE_THREAD_LOCAL_FOR_BUFFER_RECYCLING`: disabling of which will prevent reuse of `BufferRecycler`.
You could maybe try 2.6.0-SNAPSHOT with this option to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to modify code locally, re-compile, commenting out pieces until it works. This is not an extension point meant to be modified or accessed by users.